# How keep open mdl-menu with html select when it's click?

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

Here is an example of what is happening, when the dropdown list in the menu is clicked the menu is dismissed. Thanks in advance

```css
#menu{
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.light_blue-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<nav class="mdl-navigation">
   <button id="menu" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"     style="background-color:blue">
   </button>
   <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="menu" id="ul_container">
       <p>DropDownList</p>
          <li>
             <select name="Select">
                <option value="0">Option_0</option>
                <option value="1">Option_1</option>
                <option value="2">Option_2</option>
                <option value="3">Option_3</option>
                <option value="4">Option_4</option>
                <option value="5">Option_5</option>
             </select>
          </li> 
   </ul>      
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.mdl-menu').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
document.querySelector('.mdl-menu').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#menu{
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.light_blue-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<nav class="mdl-navigation">
   <button id="menu" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"     style="background-color:blue">
   </button>
   <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="menu" id="ul_container">
       <p>DropDownList</p>
          <li>
             <select name="Select">
                <option value="0">Option_0</option>
                <option value="1">Option_1</option>
                <option value="2">Option_2</option>
                <option value="3">Option_3</option>
                <option value="4">Option_4</option>
                <option value="5">Option_5</option>
             </select>
          </li> 
   </ul>      
</nav>
```

Comment: You're welcome (to StackOverflow). ... :: }<(((*> ::)